# Add an image to confirmation email using Devise 3 and Rails 4

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, asset-pipeline, devise-confirmable

Using Devise 3 and Rails 4, I would like to add an image to my confirmation email.

I tried...

**Views/Devise/Mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb**

```
<%= image_tag("my_image.png") %>
```

...the image however is showing up as a default placeholder question mark.

How should I correctly access the asset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

`<%= image_tag("my_image.png") %>`

With

`<%= image_tag "http://mydomain.com/path/to/my_image.png" %>`

For example:

`<%= image_tag "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" %>`

The above example would add Google Logo in your email body.

If you want your own image to be shown then replace

`mydomain.com` : Your domain name

`/path/to` :  Path to your folder where `my_image.png` resides

Comment: Would you kindly explain how to serve the image If it resides in app/assets/images . How would I link to it then using image_tag?

Comment: @moeabdol would you like to post a new SO question and I can answer for you?

Comment: It should be `<%= image_tag "http://www.yourdomiain.com/assets/images/logo.png" %>`

Answer (score 5):

There is another way to supply an image in a Devise confirmation email - attach it to the letter.

See the instructions:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Inline+Attachments
- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer

1.
Create your own mailer:

**app/mailers/my_devise_mailer.rb**

```
class MyDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer

  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that your mailer uses the devise views

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    attachments.inline['logo.jpg'] = File.read("app/assets/images/logo.jpg")
    super
  end

end
```

2.
In your **config/initializers/devise.rb**, set `config.mailer="MyDeviseMailer"`.

3.
In your **app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb** use

```
<p><%= image_tag(attachments['logo.jpg'].url, width: '120', height: '120') %></p>
```